# IBM Worklight - App only starts once; gives error after saying Failed to load webpage

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, yeoman

I created an iphone app in IBM Worklight using Angularjs, generated by yeoman.  Everything works fine in the simulator, but when I deploy to my physical device, the app will open only once.  Using the iphone configuration utility, the error reported merely says Failed to load webpage at that url.

I do not understand why it would only work one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It don't think this has got anything to do with angularjs and/or yeoman.

It sounds like you've changed the HTML filename in the common folder and the `mainFile` value in application-descriptor.xml. Changing the mainFile value used to cause a bug after launching the app a second time - it wouldn't find the resource, the HTML file.

If you indeed did the above, try the following:

1. Rename the application folder name to match the renaming you've done above
2. update the `ID` attribute of the `application` element in application-descriptor.xml to match as well
3. Make sure to delete the native folder
4. Re-build and deploy the app

This should now make the app launch a second, third, ... time as well.
Fixed in the upcoming Worklight 6.1.0.

Comment: Fantastic.  Changing the file name back to <project name> worked for me in the meantime, but your solution solves it better than that.  

The reason I mentioned yeoman is because the generator automatically starts me with 'index.html' and I pointed my worklight app descriptor to that.  Apologies for being misleading with that piece to the puzzle.